# Select li with innerHtml that equals "X" in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I have the following:

```
<ul>
  <li>Bob</li>
  <li>Chris</li>
  <li>Julie</li>
</ul>
```

Can I select just the `li` that has the `innerHtml' equal to "Chris"?

Something like

```
$('ul').child('li' html:'Chris'); // I dunno..
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **[`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)** to select elements that contain the specified text.

```js
$('ul li:contains(Chris)').css('color','red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Bob</li>
  <li>Chris</li>
  <li>Julie</li>
</ul>
```

---

For exact match use **[`filter()`](http://that%20contain%20the%20specified%20text.)** method

```js
$('ul li').filter(function() {
  return $(this).html() == 'Chris';
}).css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Bob</li>
  <li>Chris</li>
  <li>Julie</li>
</ul>
```